# PHP / MySQL - Write and check UPPERCASE in database

Tags: php, mysql, uppercase

I have the following code to write the name and score of a player into a highscore table. How can I write the 'name' in uppercase into the database?

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['score'])) {
$name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']));
$score = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score']));

$checkExist = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `score` FROM `$tbl_name` WHERE `name` = '$name'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkExist);

if (mysql_num_rows($checkExist) > 0){
    if ($score > $row['score']){
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `$tbl_name` SET `score` = '$score' WHERE `name` = '$name'");
    } else {
        // ERROR MSG: Your new score is lower.(not updating the database)
    }
} else {
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$tbl_name` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");
}
```

Comment: [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) is one way. There is an SQL method though, but I rather you ["Google" that](http://www.google.com).

Answer (score 3):

`$name = strtoupper(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])));`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Answer (score 0):

Either use `strtoupper()` in PHP, or `UPPER()` in MySQL: both do exactly the same, it's *up* to you.